# Как создать плейлист в плеер?

Tags: visual-basic

Покажите простой пример плейлиста, лучше дайте исходник.

Answer (score 1):

- [Programming Playlists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd892425(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [Visual Basic .NET Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd873726(v=vs.85).aspx)